# Empty response when pushing arrays to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel

I can't figure out why my multidimensional array in JSON always is empty in the response. If I declare my JSON static like this..

```
  var data = {
    foo:  123,
    bar:  456,
    cars: [
      { name:"Ford", test: 4},
      { name:"BMW" },
      { name:"Fiat"}
    ]
  };
```

Response:

```
(index):78 Success
(index):79 {"foo":123,"bar":456,"cars":[{"name":"Ford","test":4},{"name":"BMW"},{"name":"Fiat"}]}
```

So this works, but when I add arrays dynamically the response is empty..

```
  var data = {
    foo:  123,
    bar:  456,
  }; 

  data.cars: [];

  function getMousePos(e) {
      return {x:e.clientX,y:e.clientY};
  }

  document.onmousemove=function(e) {
      var mousePos = getMousePos(e);

      data.cars.push({x: mousePos.x, y: mousePos.y});

      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  };
  var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // Most browsers.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // IE8 & IE9
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
};

var url = 'http://localhost:80/t';
var method = 'POST';
var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);

xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log("Success");
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  console.log("Error");
};

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

The console before I send..

```
{"foo":123,"bar":456,"cars":[{"x":320,"y":8},{"x":321,"y":20}]}
```

The response I get..

```
(index):79 Success
(index):80 {"foo":123,"bar":456,"cars":[]}
```

The "cars" array always ends up empty in the response when I push arrays to the JSON string. I have read every stackoverflow thread I can find about this but can't figure out the problem.

Response code on server

```
public function getJson(Request $request) {

    $content = $request->json()->all();


    return $content;
}
```

I should also point out that i'm using Laravel 5.4 on the response server.

Comment: `data.cars: []` should be `data.cars = []` I believe

Comment: you're sending the request immediatly before `data.cars` even gets the chance to be filled with mouse input

Comment: @Teh Yes you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could see 2 mistakes:

1. Define Cars object like data.cars = [];  rather using data.cars: [];
2. Ajax calls are asynchronous in nature, based on the code which you have written **xhr.send** will be called before **document.onmousemove** function.
   onmousemove requires **mousemove** event to trigger but xhr.send is not inside any function and hence getting called as soon as page is getting loaded.

So you will have to make 2 changes:

1. Define Cars object like data.cars = [];
2. Call **xhr.send** method after assignment of data in **mousemove** function i.e. inside mousemove or other function